# Did I release the object correctly?

Tags: objective-c

This problem confused me a lot.
selectedDate is also a object of NSDate.
if I delete the line at mark1, this project will run normally.
if not, this project will down after I call this method.
where is the problem?
Thanks a lot!

```
NSDate *selectedData_c = [self.selectedDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 60 * 8];
self.label = (UILabel *)[nibLoadedCell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@-%@",[[selectedData_c description] substringWithRange:yearRange],[[selectedData_c description] substringWithRange:monthRange],[[selectedData_c description] substringWithRange:dayRange]];
[selectedData_c release];           // mark1
return cell;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to release it, it is an `autorelease` object. Usually you only release stuff you `alloc`ed or `copy`ed yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
selectedData_c
```

need not  to be release as `dateByAddingTimeInterval` method will return autorelease object.

Answer (score 1):

No. "dateByAddingTimeInterval" does not contain the words alloc, copy, retain, or mutableCopy. Thus, you're not responsible for that memory. This is a objective-c naming standard.

Note that if you want that data to stick around after string is released, you should copy it; by the contract, you're not responsible for that memory, but you are also not guaranteed that it will last beyond the scope of the object that gave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `release` it, it's `autorelease`'d.  Please read [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) posted by Apple.  They make sense and they make memory management on the iOS platform quite easy.